# jQuery function is resetting dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop-down menu in my page, it's something like this:

```
   <select id="my_dropdown" name="my_dropdown">
       <option value="one">ONE</option>
       <option value="two">TWO</option>
       <option value="three">THREE</option>
   </select>
   <input type="text" size="10" id="foobar" value="0" />
```

And my jQuery code is:

```
   $('#foobar').keyup(function(){
       notOptionOne();
   }

   function notOptionOne() {
       if ( !$('#my_dropdown').val('one') ) {
           alert('Option ONE was not selected');
       }
   }
```

No matter what is the selection on my dropdown, when I enter any text on the input box, it will show up the alert box and will reset my dropdown selection back to one. I want to keep my selection on where I leave when I close the alert box or do anything else. What is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   function notOptionOne() {
   if ( $('#my_dropdown').val()!='one' ) {
       alert('Option ONE was not selected');
   }
   }
```

The val() function in jQuery can both get a value or set a value. when you pass a parameter to it, what jQuery do is to set the value of the control. If no parameter, get value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#my_dropdown').val() !== 'one'
```

`$('#my_dropdown').val('one')` is jquery wrapper, array-like object. That is why `!$('#my_dropdown').val('one')` is always `false` and you don't get an `alert`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#my_dropdown').change(function(){
   if ($(this).val() != 'one') {
      alert('Option ONE was not selected');
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#my_dropdown').val('one')` will set #my_dropdown's value as `one` (even in if construction).

You should get the value of `#my_dropdown` element and compare it with string `one`:

```
function notOptionOne() {
    if ($('#my_dropdown').val() != "one") {
       alert('Option ONE was not selected');
    }
}
```